# Why is Promise.all needed for Array.map Array.forEach asynchronous operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using NodeJS (ExpressJS) server, have the following code:

```
let caseScore = 0
await questions.map(async q => {
  caseScore += await q.grade() // Queries database and gets questions, finds score
}))
console.log(caseScore)
>> Output: 0
```

However, it appears that q.grade() finishes executing after the request is finished.  I put a console.log() within q.grade, and it shows up after response is sent.  Clearly this is executed asynchronously.  So later I did this:

```
let caseScore = 0
await Promise.all(questions.map(async q => {
  caseScore += await q.grade() // Queries database and gets questions, finds score
})))
console.log(caseScore)
>> Output: 2
```

It works perfectly.  Can someone explain to me why Promise.all is needed?  Also, if I switch .map for .forEach, Promise.all errors, what is the correct way to do this for .forEach?

Comment: You've demonstrated why it's needed with your first example that doesn't work. And there isn't a correct way to do it with forEach, which is why you have to use map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `await` an array of promises, you wait for an array which is not a promise (even though it contain promises inside). `await` will immediately resolve values that are not a `Promise`. It's like if you did `await 'hello'`, that would be resolving instantly.

`Promise.all` is a util that exposes a new `Promise` that resolves only when all the promises in the array passed as an argument are resolved. Since it's creates it's own promise, you can `await` on `Promise.all`.

[EDIT]
Careful, do not use await in loops like this

```
for (var q of questions) {
  caseScore += await q.grade();
}
```

The reason is that it translates to

```
questions[0].grade().then(score => 
  return questions[1].grade().then(score => 
    return questions[2].grade().then(score => 
      return questions[3].grade().then(score => 
        // ...
      );
    );
  );
);
```

it creates a lots of context in memory and makes everything serial which is not taking advantage of javascript async nature

if you want to have a sum or some values shared between promises you can use a context object

```js
async function grade1() {
  this.sum += await getSumFromServer();
  this.nbOfTasks += 1;
}

async function grade2() {
  this.sum += await getSumFromServer();
  this.nbOfTasks += 1;
}

async function grade3() {
  this.sum += await getSumFromServer();
  this.nbOfTasks += 1;
}

async function main() {
  const context = {
    sum: 0,
    nbOfTasks: 0,
  }
  
  const promisesWithContext = [grade1, grade2, grade3]
    .map(fn => fn.call(context));

  await Promise.all(promisesWithContext);
  
  console.log(context);
}

main();

// STUB
function getSumFromServer() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(Math.random() * 100)
    }, 1000)
  });
}
```

Comment: Ohhh I see.  .map returns an array of promises, which executes instantly with await (because Promise[] is not a promise).  That makes complete sense.  I guess you could use a for loop and await each one, or you can Promise.all to merge them, and await the whole thing. thanks!!

Comment: I would advise against using await in loops, I'll update my answer with why

Comment: Thanks, I guess is this the same as await Promise.all(array.map(async...))?  or does that also translate to lots of context?  Thanks for the suggestion to avoid for() { async} loops.

Comment: Yes. I skipped a depth of async in my last example to simplify reading but it's the same :)

Answer (score 4):

You should have to wait for all async calls to be completed. That is the reason why **promise.all** needed.

It converts the set of promises to a single promise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  That makes sense.  I guess there is no way to to this with async/await?  Also why doesn't it work with forEach?

Comment: @user6269972 because `forEach` will not await for all Promises (async functions) to be completed.

Answer (score 2):

Array.prototype.map works like that.

```js
Array.prototype.map = function(callback) {
  var results = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    results.push(callback(this[i], i));
  }
  return result;
}
```

In your code your callback returns `Promise` and Array.map returns array of `Promise`. Because it doesn't awaits for callback to be completed. Array.forEach also will not work for you because it doesn't awaits callback too.

The best way to solve your problem is using `Promise.all` to convert array of `Promise` into a single `Promise` and await it.

```js
await Promise.all(questions.map(async q => {
  caseScore += await q.grade();
}));
```

Or using simple `for` loop like that.

```js
for (var q of questions) {
  caseScore += await q.grade();
}
```

Comment: this answers the `forEach` vs `map`, maybe we could add an explanation that do not rely on typescript types knowledge.

Comment: @zeachco  could you explain your request? I did not get what you need. (please use simple english, my english level is not good)

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.  Is there a way to do this with async/await?  I would think that "await question.map(async.." would await resolving of Promise[]

Comment: @MisirJafarov I meant that `Promise[]` is not familiar to everyone, better make a code example. I also would advise against using a loop with `await` inside. It chains promises and could result in awful performance issues